# Filter array of objects by array of strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My Object:

```
const searchFor = ['appInfo', 'questions'];
```

My Data:

```
const data = [
  { id: '1', data: 'jobInfo' },
  { id: '2', data: 'appInfo' },
  { id: '3', data: 'documents' },
  { id: '4', data: 'questions' },
];
```

I am expecting the final result to be:

```
[
  { id: '2', data: 'appInfo' },
  { id: '4', data: 'questions' },
];
```

My try was that I can filter with one item with fixed value

```
const result = Object.keys(searchFor).map((key) => data.filter((obj) => obj.data === key))
```

I getting `array of arrays` but I need `array of object` and more over I not sure if there is any better way to do this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Array methods [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (because `searchFor` is an Array.)

```js
const searchFor = ['appInfo', 'questions'];

const data = [
  { id: '1', data: 'jobInfo' },
  { id: '2', data: 'appInfo' },
  { id: '3', data: 'documents' },
  { id: '4', data: 'questions' },
];

const result = data.filter(item => searchFor.includes(item.data));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) together with [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const searchFor = ['appInfo', 'questions'],
      data = [{id:'1',data:'jobInfo'},{id:'2',data:'appInfo'},{id:'3',data:'documents'},{id:'4',data:'questions'},],
      
      result = data.filter(({data:d}) => searchFor.includes(d))
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and it works and it's impressive, I have upvoted it :)  but did not accepted it because in vs-code with airbnb esLint I am getting this alert `'data' is already declared in the upper scope.` highlighted to `({data})`. Also, I don't know what's going on here `({data})`, is it doing `({data: data})`? The accepted answer looks more simple to me.

Comment: Destructuring is a very powerful technique and is widely used with front-end libraries, like React.js. If you wish to master that and avoid above eslint alert, you may unpack your `data` property into the variable, named `d`, for example (`data.filter(({data:d}) => searchFor.includes(d))`) or you may proceed with solution you've chosen if it feels more comfortable for you. However, if you would share your concerns before making your decision I would gladly help you to sort things out.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the key/objects pairs and map the found objects.

```js
const
    searchFor = ['appInfo', 'questions'],
    data = [{ id: '1', data: 'jobInfo' }, { id: '2', data: 'appInfo' }, { id: '3', data: 'documents' }, { id: '4', data: 'questions' }],
    result = searchFor.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        new Map(data.map(o => [o.data, o]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice solution, however it may outperform `filter()` only for certain ultimate use cases (e.g. [when what you're searching for is not even there most of the times](https://jsbench.me/zkkbttbkjw/1))

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, it was just an idea for a use case of Map. maybe the speed is better in the future by having better (optimizing) compilers ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
const searchFor = ['appInfo', 'questions'];


const data = [
  { id: '1', data: 'jobInfo' },
  { id: '2', data: 'appInfo' },
  { id: '3', data: 'documents' },
  { id: '4', data: 'questions' },
];

var res = data.filter(i=> searchFor.includes(i.data))
console.log(res)
```

If you wanna reduce the complexity to O(N), you may consider this:

```js
const searchFor = ['appInfo', 'questions'];


        const data = [
          { id: '1', data: 'jobInfo' },
          { id: '2', data: 'appInfo' },
          { id: '3', data: 'documents' },
          { id: '4', data: 'questions' },
        ];

var hashTable = {};

    searchFor.forEach(i=> hashTable[i] = true );

    var res = data.filter(i=>{
     return hashTable[i.data]
    });

    console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const results = data.filter(item => searchFor.includes(item.data)):
console.log(results):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const result = data.filter((rec, id) => {
  if (searchFor.indexOf(rec.data) > -1) {
    return rec
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(data.filter(element=>{
   return searchFor.includes(element.data)
}));
```

The idea here is you have to  take elements of data and then have to filter each element of data after matching with search for object  .since search for the object that contains your filter criteria so it has to be nested within external iteration i.e filter method we have passed on data object .

Comment: May I ask what's the extra value you expected to bring into this thread of almost identical answers hours after OP had made his (strange) choice of accepted solution? MDN docs (I'm referring to in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62561480/11299053)) explain perfectly both used methods in the best possible way. You didn't even seem to bother to make a live-snippet to demonstrate your code in action.